# How to create a .exe from a .jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, ant, git-bash

I want to make a .exe from a .jar (yes, I know that it defeats the purpose but I need this to be easily executable).

I already had a .jar file generated but when running it I encountered several problems:

- The launch4j gave me a UnsupportedClassVersionError (compiled by a more recent version of Java Runtime)
- Tried to install a more recent JRE and JDK to rebuild the .jar but then intellij didn't recognize the "ant" command because I'm on windows I assumed (since it also doesn't recognize stuff like "ls").
- I tried using the command with git bash, same thing. I've tried getting apache ant to work to rebuild the .jar but still not even "ant -version" works.
- Rebuilt the .jar without ant using intellij built-in project-structure, artifacts, etc build thing. Got the .jar rebuilt but the first error persists.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/academiadecodigo/thunderstructs/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

I'm not sure what to actually do at this point, as I'm not very experienced with this stuff. I have a build.xml in the intellij project, and was able to generate a .jar with just the ant command on a mac. If I recall correctly the macs run on java 7 if that helps anything, and I have java 8 on this one.

Comment: Use a newer java, and then you may try to use jlink (which comes with java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to version mismatch. You have compiled your code using Java 11 (class file version 55.0) and your current JRE is version 8 (class file version 52.0).

Try upgrading your JRE to version 11 or downgrading your JDK to version 8.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cross-platform Java executable wrapper developed by Grzegorz Kowal that can be found on this url: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Here is an easy guide on how you can use the tool: https://medium.com/@sulabh4/how-to-make-a-executable-file-from-your-java-code-3f521938ae5c